# Inheritance: __init__ overriden

Tags: python, inheritance

I have 2 classes who I want both to inherit from another class. 
These 2 classes already have `def __init__`, defined. Now, I want these 2 classes to inherit a method that requires a series of parameters (arguments). But in the 2 classes that should inherit, the `def __init__` gets overriden.

How can I solve this problem? I read about constructors in Python vs. `def __init__`. Could I maybe create a custom constructor for the method? I am quite new at classes in general.

EDIT:

Here's what I'm attemping. This is a GUI project. This is the main class:

```
class Error:
    def __init__(self, check0, check1, check2, check3, check4, check5, check6, check7, check8, check9, check10, check11,
                    check12, check13, check14, check15):
        self.check0 = check0
        self.check1 = check1
        self.check2 = check2
        self.check3 = check3
        self.check4 = check4
        self.check5 = check5
        self.check6 = check6
        self.check7 = check7
        self.check8 = check8
        self.check9 = check9
        self.check10 = check10
        self.check11 = check11
        self.check12 = check12
        self.check13 = check13
        self.check14 = check14
        self.check15 = check15

    def feedbackOnError(self):
        feedback = ''
        global feedback

        if self.check0 == False:
            feedback0 = "You didn't provide a name and/or mail"
            feedback = feedback0

        if self.check3 == False:
            feedback3 = "You didn't provide a valid year (you used over 4 digits or none)"
            feedback = feedback3

        if self.check4 == False:
            feedback4 = "You didn't provide a valid year (you used letters)"
            feedback = feedback4

        if self.check5 == False:
            feedback5 = "You didn't provide a valid month (you used over 2 digits or none)"
            feedback = feedback5

        if self.check6 == False:
            feedback6 = "You didn't provide a valid month (you used letters)"
            feedback = feedback6

        if self.check7 == False:
            feedback7 = "You didn't provide a valid month (you used a number above 12)"
            feedback = feedback7

        if self.check8 == False:
            feedback8 = "You didn't provide a valid month '00' is not a month)"
            feedback = feedback8

        if self.check9 == False:
            feedback9 = "You didn't provide a valid day (you used letters)"
            feedback = feedback9

        if self.check10 == False:
            feedback10 = "You didn't provide a valid day '00' is not a day)"
            feedback = feedback10

        if self.check11 == False:
            feedback11 = "You didn't provide a valid day (you used a number above 31)"
            feedback = feedback11

        if self.check12 == False:
            feedback12 = "You didn't provide a valid day (you used over 2 digits or none)"
            feedback = feedback12

        if self.check13 == False:
            feedback13 = "Your month doesn't match up with your day (February has 29 during leap year)"
            feedback = feedback13

        if self.check14 == False:
            feedback14 = "Your month doesn't match up with your day (February has 28 during normal years)"
            feedback = feedback14

        if self.check15 == False:
            feedback15 = "Your chosen month and day don't match up (You used '31' for a month with only 30)"
            feedback = feedback15

        if self.check1 == False:
            feedback1 = "You used characters that are not permitted: \n / ' * \\ _ > < [ ] ( ) | + { } % & ! \" # = ? ^ ~ . , ; :"
            feedback = feedback1

        if self.check2 == False:
            feedback2 = "You used characters that are not permitted: \n / ' * \\ _ > < [ ] ( ) | + { } % & ! \" # = ? ^ ~ . , ; :"
            feedback = feedback2
```

This is the classes I want to inherit the main class:

```
class AddDialog(sized_controls.SizedDialog, Error):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddDialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class EditDialog(sized_controls.SizedDialog, Error):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditDialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: You're going to need to show us your code if we're to point out what you did wrong.

Comment: Try calling `super` in your `__init__` methods.

Comment: It's unclear how `__init__` is related to your "inherit a method" problem... or twhat the problem IS.

Comment: Usually, you decide to inherit from a base class at the beginning of the design process. Changing the base class almost certainly means redesigning the children.

Comment: ok I've edited my post, should've thought about showing code before.

Comment: Are you asking about how to make sure both parent `__init__` methods get called? Because currently only the non-`Error` version will be called using `super`.

Comment: Well I need the method and the method needs input which it gets from the Error constructor. So wouldn't I need to somehow make sure `Error`'s constructor/initializer is used?

Comment: Did you write `sized_controls.SizedDialog`, or is that from some library?

Comment: It's from a library

Comment: There are two possibilities here: 1) `SizedDialog` is not supposed to be put before another class (`Error` in this case) in the method-resolution order, or 2) the library has a bug (because `SizedDialog` doesn't call `super().__init__()` in its `__init__()` method).

Comment: @Kevin. Error and SizedDialog are unrelated classes, so there's a third option where you just have to call it manually.

Comment: You modify global state from inside a method? Is that common practice in GUI programming? That seems fraught with pitfalls.

Comment: Not sure, I am new to everything programming and this is my first GUI. I don't know what a global state is.

Comment: This design looks like a nightmare. Each of those "checks" should be probably raising an exception immediately, not being passed as arguments to an object constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that you are only executing one of the two base-class `__init__` methods that you have, but you would like to pass arguments and invoke both.

`super` will only the method that appears first in the method resolution order (MRO), so you will have to call at least one of the `__init__`s "manually". You will also have to decide which arguments to the derived `__init__` go where, since you will have to pass in both sets of arguments. For the sake of this example, I will pretend that error only takes three required positional arguments (`check0`, `check1` and `check2`):

```
class AddDialog(sized_controls.SizedDialog, Error):
    def __init__(self, check0, check1, check2, *args, **kwargs):
        Error.__init__(self, check0, check1, check2)
        SizedDialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

On a related note, I would recommend that you refactor your code to use a list because honestly, 16 arguments is ridiculous. Using `*args`, you can avoid refactoring too much additional code:

```
class Error:
    feedback_strings = [
        "You didn't provide a name and/or mail",
        "You used characters that are not permitted: \n / ' * \\ _ > < [ ] ( ) | + { } % & ! \" # = ? ^ ~ . , ; :",
        "You used characters that are not permitted: \n / ' * \\ _ > < [ ] ( ) | + { } % & ! \" # = ? ^ ~ . , ; :",
        "You didn't provide a valid year (you used over 4 digits or none)",
        "You didn't provide a valid year (you used letters)",
        # You get the idea...
    ]

    def __init__(self, *checks):
        if len(checks) != 16:
            raise ValueError('16 positional arguments are required')
        self.checks = [bool(x) for x in checks]

    def feedbackOnError(self):
        for index, check in enumerate(self.checks):
            if not check:
                return self.feedback_strings[index]
```

This code is about 10 times shorter, easier to maintain and easier to read than your existing code. I also recommend returning a value from your feedback function instead of setting a global variable. The global variable approach is a really bad idea because you really don't know who is going to modify it.

Comment: @andrew. A) The suspense is killing me. B). What do you think `super...` is doing?

Comment: This is frankly poor design.  The correct usage of `super()` is as a [chain of responsibility](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).  It is not possible in the general case for a class to know about all of the classes that come after it in the method-resolution order (at least, not without manually introspecting this information at runtime, which is massive overkill for a standard initializer method).  So this will not work in the general case and should be discouraged.

Comment: @Kevin. I could not agree with you more. However, this is what OP asked for in the most immediate literal sense.

Comment: It doesn't  seem to fix the problem. :/ Thank you though. By the way, could you explain what you did in the `feedbackOnError` method? Not familiar with how you wrote it. Also, I appreciate any comments you guys have as this is new to me and I'm learning from this

Comment: @andrew. I put the strings into a list, then just access the appropriate element of that list from a loop that checks for errors. I think you really need a basic Python tutorial before you continue if you are having any trouble with either lists or loops.

Comment: Hahah no no, I am quite familiar with lists and loops, however enumerate is foreign to me

Comment: @andrew. `enumerate` is a function that returns the index along with the item being iterated. It is a Python builtin. I use it to access the correct string for the first check that turns out to be `False`.